# Batch file to parse text file line by line then check if that line exist in other text files

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

This is my first post, asking permission to ask for help here.

I have a limited knowledge with batch file. I have a script that uses FOR /f that reads a text file with one word per line then use that word as my variable.

Problem is I wanted to use that variable (each line from reference file) to check if that variable exist on all target text files, now I have no idea how to create a batch file for this purpose.
I spent time searching for an answer but cannot find any, should there be a similar batch file here in StackOverflow, please give me the link.

Goal: Count how many PC have the packages from reference file packageList.txt. I already gathered the list of packages on all PC and saved them as PC1_bare.txt, PC2_bare.txt, PC3_bare.txt and so on...

Example:

My text files are...

**packageList.txt**

```
Acrobat

Chrome

Flash

Photoshop

msOffice
```

**Contents of PC1_bare.txt:**

```
Acrobat

Chrome

Flash

Photoshop

msOffice
```

**Contents of PC2_bare.txt:**

```
Acrobat

Chrome

Flash

msOffice
```

**Contents of PC3_bare.txt:**

```
Acrobat

Flash

msOffice
```

**Contents of pcList:**

```
PC1_bare.txt

PC2_bare.txt

PC3_bare.txt
```

**Expected results:**

```
Acrobat is installed to 3 PC

Chrome is installed to 2 PC

Flash is installed to 3 PC 

Photoshop is installed to 1 PC

msOffice is installed to 3 PC
```

Comment: What have you tried before coming here? Please include any code that you already have.

Comment: I was stucked in this line, no idea how to parse two text files. 


for /F %%I in (%~dp0packageList.txt) do call :Check_Files %%I

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick -

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in (packageList.txt) do (
    set count=0
    for /f %%b in (pcList) do for /f %%c in (%%b) do if "%%c"=="%%a" set /a count+=1
    echo %%a is installed to !count! PCs
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply. I am getting... _msOffice is installed to !count! PCs_ Don't know how to make it like. _msOffice is installed to 3 PCs _

Comment: No worries, managed to fix. Have to add in the beggining a _setlocal enableDelayedExpansion_



Thanks a lot unclemeat

Comment: @htan68 sorry about that, yeah that's all that was needed.

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

:: make a tempfile
:maketemp
SET "tempfile=%temp%\%random%"
IF EXIST "%tempfile%*" (GOTO maketemp) ELSE (ECHO.>"%tempfile%a")

FOR /f "delims=" %%p IN (pclist.txt) DO (>>"%tempfile%a" TYPE "%%p")
FOR /f "delims=" %%p IN (packagelist.txt) DO (
 FOR /f "delims=" %%c IN ('findstr /i /b /e /L /c:"%%p" "%tempfile%a"^|find /c /v ""') DO echo %%p is installed to %%c PC
)
DEL /Q "%tempfile%a"

GOTO :EOF
```

Make a temporary file.
concatenate the lists of files found into that file.
for each package, find the packagename as a `/L` (literal) that both `/b` and `/e` (begins and ends) a line, `/i` ignoring case `/c:` "spaces may appear in the packagename", then `FIND` and `count` (/c) the number of `not empty` (/v "") lines produced and show this count along with the packagename.

(Also works with 'installed on 0 PCs')

Comment: Thank you Magoo
, this one works too. I will need this if 0 count is required.